# I'm trying to delete everything but the email but I get the opposite

Tags: regex, email, notepad++

I tried to search in other questions here but none seem to work for me
I'm using notepadd++ and i'm trying to remove everything but email from a email list where everything is in the same line.

Example:

```
| RONNAN FERREIRA | RENANRFCRON@GMAIL.COM 17933 | RONNE YAN CANAVARRO DE ASSIS |
```

This regex seems to select every email perfecly:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

When i put `$1` or `\1` on "replace with" it just delete all the emails, i want it to do the opposite.

Comment: Use capture groups to make sure you carry emails into your replacement. Use `(.*?)([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)(.*?)` and `$2` for the replacement field.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you! it worked! now i just need to insert a paragraph after each email using $2\n

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\G.*?(\S+@\S+)(?:(?=.*@)|.*$)`
- Replace with: `$1` <-- there is a space after $1, you may add any character you want as delimiter
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\G              # restart from last match position
.*?             # 0 or more any character, not greedy
(\S+@\S+)       # group 1, an email
(?:             # non capture group
  (?=.*@)       # positive lookahead, check if we have an @  after
 |            # OR
  .*$           # 0 or more any character until end of line
)               # end group
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't find two emails in one line. So you should delete the `.*$` part at the end.

Comment: @CennoxX: It'not said that there is more than one email on each line.

Comment: Yes, i have multiple emails in the same line, sorry for not explaining it well. anyway, i removed the .*$ at the end and now it will just keep the first email from each line,

Comment: @AndreEusébio: see my edit, it works for any number of emails in a line

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to either capture an email format in a capturing group, or match all parts divided by 1+ or more horizontal whitespace chars that do not contain an @.

To match only the spaces after an email except for the last one, you could make use of a [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) which has the form `(?(?=regex)then|else)`

In the replacement use `$1`

```
([^\h@]+@[^\h@]+(?(?=[^@\r\n]*@)\h+))|\h*(?<!\S)[^\h@]+(?:\h+[^\h@]+)*(?!\S)\h*
```

In parts:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\h@]+@[^\h@]+` Match an e-mail like format
  - `(?(?=[^@\r\n]*@)\h+)` Conditional, match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars if there is another email
- `)` Close group

  - `|` Or
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `[^\h@]+(?:\h+[^\h@]+)*` Repeat matching the parts that don't have an @
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ycp0ht/1)

A test for the example content with multiple email addresses

```
| RONNAN FERREIRA | RENANRFCRON@GMAIL.COM 17933 | RONNE YAN CANAVARRO DE ASSIS | RENANRFCRON@GMAIL.COM 17933 |
```

[image]